# Ms Access Validation - All the first 2 characters from Column 2 should be same group by the value from Column1

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to validate whether all the first 2 letters from column 'Code' should be the same (Either 'GB' or 'OR') for all similar values in column 'AccountNumber'
Eg: Both the code values for account number '129610896' starts with GB, likewise all the code values for account number '184046309' starts with OR. So both the scenarios are valid. 
But the code values for account number '248038839' differs (One starts with GL and another starts with OR) which is an invalid scenario.

```
AccountNumber   Code    BillAmount
129610896   GLB2B001    30000
129610896   GLB2B032    30001
184046309   OR2B001 30002
184046309   OR2B032 40003
184046309   OR3B032 30004
248038839   GLB2B002    50005
248038839   OR2B001 30006
```

What is the query to validate this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

The following will return `AccountNumber`s where this is not true:

```
select AccountNumber
from table
group by AccountNumber
having min(left(code, 2)) = max(left(code, 2));
```